# Calling super in abstract class

Tags: java

first things first, I'm a C# developer haha!

I have an abstract class in my program called Game, which has a few methods that do stuff like update and render the game. I was just wondering, if it's proper to call a super method, inside the extended class, or is there something else I should be using?

```
public void initialize()
{
    // Do a bunch of stuff here

    // and call the base method
    super.initialize(); // Is this proper coding convention for abstract classes, or should I use something different?
}
```

Comment: yes, it is proper call

Comment: First, this has nothing to do with C# so remove the C# tag. Second, I don't understand your question. Why do you want to call super()? Is there a reason, if so, what? If you don't have a reason, why are you trying to use it?

Comment: If you need to call super, just do it, There is nothing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

An abstract class can extend an other class (abstract or not), so this is valid.

```
public class MySuperClass {
    public String getString(){ 
        return "Hello";
    }
}

public abstract class MyClass extends MySuperClass{
    public String getString(){
        return super.getString() + " world !";
    }
}
```

What **you can't do** is call this method if in the super class it is defined as abstract. It doesn't depends on the `abstract class` but on the `abstract method`

```
public abstract class MySuperClass {
    public abstract String getString();
}
```

Give a compile error :

> abstract method getString() in MySuperClass cannot be accessed directly

Answer (score 0):

It is neither "proper" or "improper" in the general sense.  Whether you can or should do this depends entirely on how you (or someone else) has designed the superclass.  And if you are designing the superclass, what you need to do is to decide:

- whether there is a need to "initialize" (or whatever) the superclass, and
- whether you should do it at the start or end of the method in the subclass.

Basically it is up to you to decide ...